# ¿Máximo tamaño de fichero para LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE en Aurora MySQL?

Tags: mysql, aws

Tengo entendido que en la configuración de MySQL hay un atributo llamado `max_allowed_packet` cuyo valor máximo es `1073741824 Bytes`, lo que vendrían a ser 1.07GB.

Entiendo que si ejecuto una sentencia `LOAD DATA LOCAL FILE`, el CSV no puede superar 1.07GB, sin embargo, el fichero pesa 2.3GB y me lo cargado correctamente, eso sí, luego de una espera de 55 minutos.

¿Cuál es el límite de Aurora (MySQL)?
¿Es más rápido cargar N ficheros pequeños o uno que pese muchos GB?